# Add button above UIAlertView overlay

Tags: ios, uialertview

I want to add button above alert's overlay rather than in its content.
[image]

I try to add button in the window, and bring it to front. However, the button is still below the overlay.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
window.addSubview(button)
window.bringSubviewToFront(button)
```

Is there way not to use custom alert view? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't as this is part of Apple's private API (The views within `UIAlertView`)

You'll need your own custom implementation of `UIAlertView` to do this.